# Реализация заполнения таблицы данными при помощи цикла (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, циклы, openserver, while

```
declare @i int;
set @i = 1;
set @a = 0.0001;
while @i < 10

begin
set @i = @i + 1;
INSERT INTO `sha224zero` (`sha224`) VALUES (SHA2(@a, 224));
set @a = @a + 0.0001;
end;
```

Думаю логика понятна, но ввиду незнания синтаксиса и тонкостей языка, реализовать я не могу.. Возможно необходимо подключать какие-то библиотеки.. Очень прошу Вашей помощи!

Comment: 0.0001 не представимо точно - рискуете...

Comment: можно конкретнее? Буду крайне признательна совету как можно реализовать данную задачу. Возможно сторонними средствами? Php?

Comment: может быть тогда через деление? INSERT INTO `sha224zero` (`sha224`) VALUES (SHA2(@i/10000, 224)); Ну это я "грубо" отобразила... чтобы было понятно, о чем я

Comment: `WHILE` нельзя использовать вне хранимых процедур и синтаксис в MySQL немного другой. [Пример решения вашей задачи](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7ee37/1)

Comment: Уважаемый vikolyada, я не знаю, как вас можно отблагодарить! Вы не представляете, как выручили меня! Вы просто профессионал своего дела! От всей души хочу пожелать Вам успехов во всех начинаниях! Я Ваша фанатка! Спасибо Вам огромное!